# Print on the page JSON boolean value with Ajax and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, rest

I used Ajax with GET request to consume rest web service.Now i have results inside my console.

Images:

Rest api which i consuming

[image]

Boolean results on console and table

[image]

And when i want to print a results inside a table only one result occours.Also i tried with each loop but it doesn't work.
Does anybody knows how can i print my boolean result from json into table ?

```
<td>{{ $num=$device->clientId }}</td>
<td id="status">
  <script>
    var num = {!! json_encode($num) !!};
    RestGet();
    function RestGet() {
      var $status=$('#status');
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:  'http://localhost:8000/api/devices/deviceAvailability/' + num,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(final) {
          $.each(final, function(i, data){
            $status.append(data);
          });
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(jqXHR.status + ' ' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</td>
```

Comment: Your code equates to `$("#status").append(false);`  What do you expect to see in the table, because you can't just append `false` - you need to append relevant DOM elements.

Comment: Also, move your jQuery script tag before your Bootstrap script tag to get rid of that error ;)

Comment: It would be good to intead false and true i write in table string is activ or not activ.Pls se my new answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use it like this:

```
$status.append(String(data));
```

and it will be shown. You have to convert the boolean value or it will think it's an empty value and do nothing.

Here is an example:

```js
$("#status").append(String(false));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="status"></div>
```